# clValid plot all the figures at the same time

Tags: r, validation, plot, shiny, cluster-analysis

I am current working on a Shiny application where clValid is used to validate the clustering algorithms. After I get the result using `intern <- clValid(...)`, I can print the three figures in the console by hitting the <Enter> button. However, for a shiny application, how can I plot all the three figures at the same time?

==== more detail

Here's typical code to get validation result

```
data(mouse)

## internal validation
express <- mouse[1:25,c("M1","M2","M3","NC1","NC2","NC3")]
rownames(express) <- mouse$ID[1:25]
intern <- clValid(express, 2:6, clMethods=c("hierarchical","kmeans","pam"),
validation="internal")
## view results
plot(intern)
```

However, figures will not plot automatically, and you have to hit <Enter> to view all the figures as follows:

```
> plot(intern)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

My question is, if Shiny is used, a plotOutput lies in the `ui.R` as:

```
mainPanel(
    plotOutput("clust_valid_plot")  
)
```

how can I print all the three plots to the `clust_valid_plot`?

Comment: It would be great if you could supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. That way others can also befit form your question, and the accompanying answer, in the future.  You can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: Use the source, luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I solved this problem by looking into the `S4` class in R. To be more specific, you can list all the solt names in `S4` class using `slotNames(intern)`. Then you can draw each line.